# Mocha runs correctly, but shows undefined

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, should.js

I use `mocha` to test my nodejs code, and the test runs just ok, but when I use `mocha test.js` to run test, it seems that the string I passed to `describe` does not show.

The code is as follows:

```
var assert = require("should");
describe("FrontEndTest", function(){
    describe('websocket establish connection', function(){
        it('should establish connection correctly', function(done){
            var res;
            var wsClient = create_ws_client('ws://127.0.0.1:9876','brain_burst');
            wsClient.on('connect', function(connection){
                res = true;
                res.should.be.true;
                done();
            });
            wsClient.on('connectFailed', function(error){
                res = false;
                res.should.be.true;
                done();
            });
            console.log(res);
        });
        it('should disconnected by server.(also, that may crash server if there is not a protocol validation)', function(done){
            var res;
            var wsClient = create_ws_client('ws://127.0.0.1:9876');
            wsClient.on('connect', function(connection){
                res = true;
                res.should.be.false;
                done();
            });
            wsClient.on('connectFailed', function(error){
                res = false;
                res.should.be.false;
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The result of `mocha` command shows:

> undefined ․․
>
> ✔ 2 tests complete (68 ms)

Why it shows `undefined` since I already pass a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the following line causing it?

```
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yes, it is because this output which variable is not assigned to a value. Thanks, pal.